# Extend a Python function that takes a C object as argument

Tags: python, c, parsing

I have a C function that takes an object as argument:

```
void fct(struct Objet * obj1) {
  ....
}
```

I would like to use this function in Python. I'm trying to parse this argument but can't find the way to. In Python:

```
static PyObject* NameMod_fct(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {

    PyObject * Obj;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", **&...**, &Obj)) { // what should I put as &Py_Type?
        return NULL;
    }

...
}
```

Comment: You said: You want to call C function `fct(struct Objet *ob1)` out of Python. How is `struct Objet` stored in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Each Python object has a reference to its type: For a `pPyObj` (of type `PyObject*`), it can be accessed with `pPyObj->ob_type`.

This should point to an instance of [`PyTypeObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html).

At this point, the answer very depends on where the resp. `PyTypeObject` is "constructed".

#### Case A: `Objet` is a Wrapper Object Written in C

This is the case, where "I feel at home" (as I got my knowledge about Python rather exclusively by writing extensions in C/C++). There should/must exist a `static` instance of `PyTypeObject` which is registered in Python initially. Just get and pass its address.

#### Case B: `Objet` is an Object of a non-C Library

Hmm... That's IMHO the most difficult case. You have to retrieve the address of the resp. `PyTypeObject` instance. This probably could be done retrieving the resp. dictionaries of Python. I cannot say in detail as I've no experience regarding this.

I guess a good start regarding this is to (re-)search about [`PyModule_GetDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_GetDict) together with [`PyImport_Import()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_Import).

#### Case C: `Objet` is an Object of a Built-In Type of Python

Last but not least – the trivial case. In this case, I wouldn't use `O` because there are a lot of other designators for the built-in types.